# In C++ public heritance Base Class call Derived class's private virtual fuction

Tags: c++, inheritance

My codes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
public:
    void print() { doPrint();}
private:
    virtual void doPrint() {cout << "Base::doPrint" << endl;}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    virtual void doPrint() {cout << "Derived::doPrint" << endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Derived *d = new Derived();
    Base* p = dynamic_cast<Base*>(d);
    p->print();
    delete d;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `Derived::doPrint`, I don't know  the answer well. Why not `Base::doPrint`? In public inheritance, why Base class can call Derived class's private virtual function?

Comment: [Find a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about *polymorphism*.

Comment: Perhaps answer to this question will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548145/low-level-details-of-inheritance-and-polymorphism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual will tell it to check what function to call. It still knows that it is a `Derived`. If you haven't put `virtual` this would not work. Read more about polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks, the `virtual` and `private` are not related. I see it well now.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, access checks are done on the *static* (compile time) type of an expression, but virtual calls use the *dynamic* (run time) type.

In your example, `*p` has static type `Base` and dynamic type `Derived`.

Answer (score 0):

Even after you've written `Base* p = dynamic_cast<Base*>(d);`, `p` is still a pointer to an instance of `Derived`.

So `p->print();` will call the function on the `Derived` class.

That's how *polymorphism* works in C++.